# Search hash in hash-table

Tags: assembly, x86, hashtable, nasm

I am coding a word-processing code in with a lot of array accesses (static array, no changes at run-time). I am hashing the string and then check if there is in my array (lookup). But what is a good implementation of it? I am doing by the simple way. Checking value per value if match to my hash input. Ideas to make it fastest?

I am currently checking:

If I use loop unrolling it will make this really different.
If I use a unordered array, it is a lot slower than a sorted array.
I'll go to see if vectorization will be fine in this case.

What do you recommend? Or better, how would you implement this algorithm?

Here's current routine (it's returns into `EAX` the index of hash in array or a negative value, if there's no match):

```
Index_of:
push edx
push ecx
push ebx
mov ecx,123456          ;hash example. in the real code,it's set by a routine.
xor ebx,ebx
mov eax,array
.LOOP1:
        cmp [eax],ecx           ;match hash?
        je .FOUND
        cmp byte [eax],0
        je .NOTFOUND
        add ebx,1
        add eax,4
        jmp .LOOP1
.NOTFOUND:
        neg eax
        jmp .DONE
.FOUND:
        mov eax,ebx
.DONE:
pop ebx
pop ecx
pop edx
ret
```

array is:

```
; hashs for examples
array:
dd 33389990
dd 1234567
dd 81919191
dd 938383737
0
```

Comment: How do you know that the thingie you're finding is actually equal to the thingie in the table?  (Hashes alone won't help with that.)

Comment: What OS? Are you running this in real mode or in protected mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of a hash table is to get the value as a function of the hash key without looping.

If you can have one value that can never be returned, you can do something like this:

```
; first fill the hash table with values, and with invalid values for the rest.
; for an example, I assume here hash table of 0x1000000h = 16777216d bytes.
; 0xFFFFFFFFF marks no match and 0xFFFFFFFE marks hash collision. 

; first fill the hash table with "no match" values.

    mov ecx,(16777216/4)
    mov eax,0xFFFFFFFF
    mov edi,hash_array
    rep stosd

; here set the values you want to return into the hash table.
; for hash collisions write 0xFFFFFFFE, and handle hash collision in the
; hash collision handling code.

; here we have some hash function that outputs 123456d with some input string.
```

**Edit:** the start address of hash array can be entered in `eax`, so it's not hardcoded.

```
    mov eax,hash_array               ; the start address of the hash array
    mov ecx,123456                   ; example hash
    call @get_value_from_hash_table  ; call to get the value from hash table

    ...
```

**Edit:** `ecx` must be scaled with 4 if hash values are dwords.

```
@get_value_from_hash_table:
    mov eax,[eax+4*ecx] 
    cmp eax,0xFFFFFFE
    ja  @no_match ; 0xFFFFFFFF ; no match
    je  @hash_collision        ; hash collision

    ; match, no hash collisions, no jumps needed.

    ...

@hash_collision:
    ; handle hash collision here, the best way depends on your data.

    ...

@no_match:
    ; handle no match here.

    ...
```

Comment: I'II try it.But does this routine given me index where `ecx` was found into array?

Comment: This is just the general framework. What values a get-hash function like this outputs in `eax` depends on what you store in the hash table. For natural language words (I assume you mean natural language words, not 16-bit CPU words) I would store the memory address of the string.

Comment: I store an array of integers. See the `array` definition in my post. Sorry if I wasn't enough clear,but also to checks the there's match `ecx` in `hash_array`,it should returns the index of such value where found. Assuming that you have seen array definition,given `81919191` in `ecx`, `eax` should returns the integer `2`.

Comment: I'm getting a seg fault.

Comment: `mov ecx,123456
 mov eax,array
 mov eax,[eax+4*ecx]
 cmp eax,0xFFFFFFE
 ja .no_match
 je .match`

Comment: Cisc instructions like repxxx will run slower on modern processors than the equivalent risc code with jumps and such.

Comment: @nrz: Maybe I'm getting a seg fault why value of `ecx` is not memory address?

Comment: @Johan `rep stosd` is used here to initialize a static hash table once, so I don't see here any need to optimize that part.

Comment: @TheMask Only `eax+4*ecx` needs to be a valid memory address (not `ecx` itself). If in real mode, check segregs `ds` & `es`. A more general issue is that a hash table is just a quick way to do `y = f(x)`, in hash table you just save the results of some function and retrieve them with the hash produced by a hash function. If you need to find the index of a value (`I_value`) in the hash table (it's not the same as `value = f(hash)`), I think you need to rethink your approach. The scaled hash (here `eax+4*ecx`) is the index. If can sort your `array`, then you can use binary search algorithm.

Comment: Using a 16 meg hash array is bound to incur cache misses. I'd say that's a fail as far as performance is concerned. It'd be much faster to do the loop. The branch-prediction will pick up on the pattern soon enough and the loops will take zero time.

Comment: @nrz: I understood. I will use sorted array + bin search

Comment: @Johan: Thank you too. I use this type of instruction,where performance is not so requested. In this case I will not use.